# Conditional probability with a bag of $10$ balls.

Tags: probability, random-variables

You draw $5$ balls out of a bag containing $10$ balls ($8$ white, $1$ red, and $1$ black) without replacement. Each ball is equally likely to be picked.  Let $R$ be the event when a red ball is selected and $B$ when a black ball is selected.

What is the $P(R)$ and $P(R|B)$?

What I have so far is that the $3$ events that can occur are:

$\{3W, 1R, 1B\}, \{4W, 1R, OB\}, \{4W, 0R, 1B\}, \{5W, OR, OB\}$

There are a total of $10$ combination $5$ choices. So 
$$
P(R) = 30/252 = P(B).
$$
Therefore, $P(R|B)$ should be: $$\frac{P(RB)}{P(B)}? \Rightarrow \frac{6/252}{30/252} = 6/30 = 1/5?$$

Mostly, this question is to validate my work. When dealing with these problems, I always remain doubtful of my answer as my logic could be incorrect when answering the question.

Comment: If you draw $5$ balls from a bag containing $10$ balls, you end up with $5$ balls out of the bag and $5$ balls left in the bag. The one and only red ball is equally likely to be in either group of $5$, so $P(R)$=$\frac12$.

Comment: How did you get $30/252$? I see that $252=\binom{10}5$, but where did $30$ come from?

Comment: I did the permutation of how the 3W in {3W, 1R, 1B} could be ordered, and how the 4W in {4W, 1R, OB} could be ordered and added them.

Comment: The number of favourables was not counted correctly. There are $\binom{8}{3}$ with three W, a red and a black, and $\binom{8}{4}$ with four white and a red.

Comment: So is P(B) still equal to P(R)? Also what would the P(RB) be now?

Comment: Would it just be $\frac{{8\choose3}}{252}$?

Answer (score 2):

> You draw 5 balls out of a bag containing 10 balls (8 white, 1 red, and 1 black) without replacement. Each ball is equally likely to be picked. Let R be the event when a red ball is selected and B when a black ball is selected.
>   What is the P(R) and P(R|B)?

$$\newcommand{\c}[2]{^{#1}{\rm C}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\d}[1]{{\rm #1}}
\d P(\d R)=\frac{\c11\c94}{\c{10}5}=\frac12=\frac5{10}\\
\d P(\d R\mid \d B)=\frac{\d P(\d R\cap\d B)}{\d P(\d B)}=\frac{\frac{\c11\c11\c83}{\c{10}5}}{\frac{\c11\c94}{\c{10}5}}=\frac49$$

[image]